# How to convert System.DateTime data to String yyyy-mm-dd format using liquid template?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to convert a System.DateTime(which is being retrieved from CRM) data to string in following format yyyy-mm-dd.

I used this {{ data | "%Y-%m-%d" }} but it doesn't seem to be working.

As for example, for this input **11/14/2019 6:00:00 AM** i am getting something like this **Y-0-14** which is not as desired.

I tried all possible combination from 
[here.](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/)

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Somehow i solved this by converting it to string using **Capture** liquid tag. Then manipulated the string and converted it to desired format.

Comment: What is `data` here?

Comment: In the given example, data is **11/14/2019 6:00:00 AM** of type **System.DateTime**.

Comment: In Shopify the command is `'now'` not data . So your data is probably not in the format recognised by the liquid filters.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below expression

```
"Converted Date":"{{ YourDate | Date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the below expression worked for me

"Converted Date":"{{ YourDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}"